# ValueError: Items of feature_columns must be either a DenseColumn or CategoricalColumn

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression, valueerror

The code is simple:

```
    x_data = np.linspace(0, 10.0, 1000000)
    y_true = (0.5 * x_data) + 5 
    x_train, x_eval, y_train, y_eval = train_test_split(x_data, y_true, test_size = 0.25, random_state=101)
    input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x':x_train}, y_train, 
                                                batch_size=8, num_epochs=None, shuffle= True)
    estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feat_cols)
    estimator.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=1000)
```

The error:

> INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 estimator.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=1000)
>         2 #eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_func, steps=1000)
>
> 8 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py
>   in **init**(self, feature_columns, units, sparse_combiner, trainable,
>   name, **kwargs)
>       498         raise ValueError(
>       499             'Items of feature_columns must be either a '
>   --> 500             'DenseColumn or CategoricalColumn. Given: {}'.format(column))
>       501 
>       502     self._units = units
>
> ValueError: Items of feature_columns must be either a DenseColumn or
>   CategoricalColumn. Given: SequenceNumericColumn(key='x', shape=(1,),
>   default_value=0.0, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None)

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine for training and prediction.

```
x_data = np.linspace(0, 10.0, 1000)
print(x_data.shape)
y_true = (0.5 * x_data) + 5
print(y_true.shape)
x_train, x_eval, y_train, y_eval = train_test_split(x_data, y_true, test_size=0.25, random_state=101)
train_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_train}, y_train, batch_size=8, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True)

features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)

estimator.train(input_fn=train_func, steps=100) # Fit the model to training data.

eval_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_eval}, batch_size=1, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

result = estimator.predict(eval_func) # Predict scores

print("predict_scores", list(result))
```